# node-edit-protection module not working in CK Editor window

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am using [node-edit-protection](http://drupal.org/project/node_edit_protection) module to alert a user if they are navigating away from a modified Node Edit form without saving. It worked fine if we edit title or any other fields. But not worked if we change the body part. I am using CKeditor in body part.

Comment: Known Bug http://drupal.org/node/1276370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `node-edit-protection.js` file in module's folder,
Find this code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     if (edit && !click) {
     click = false;
            return (Drupal.t("You will lose all unsaved work."));
     }
}
```

replace above code with following

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (typeof(Drupal.settings.ckeditor) != 'undefined' && typeof(CKEDITOR) != 'undefined' && typeof(CKEDITOR.instances) != 'undefined') {
         for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
          if (CKEDITOR.instances[i].checkDirty()) {
           edit = true;
           break;
          }
         }
        }

         if (edit && !click) {
          click = false;
          return (Drupal.t("You will lose all unsaved work."));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have one more problem. If we enable Overlay module, then it doesn't worked. Any solution to this? Please help.

Comment: check in overlay mode, that js file exist or not.

Comment: There is two js files known as overlay-child and overlay-parent in Overlay module's folder.

Comment: `node-edit-protection.js` file is missing in overlay mode.

Comment: yes. it is not there. What can I do?